# Google search console is showing far fewer external links than other sources, could this be the cause of ranking problems?

Tags: google-search-console, backlinks, google-ranking

I have been facing issue with my website ranking. I realized today that Google search console is not getting new inbound links and keep showing around 3000 links only whereas other back links checking sites are showing more than 30k to 50k back links on site.

Can I get Google to crawl more external links to my site? The number of back links on Google search console keeps decreasing day by day.

Answer (score 2):

No, this has nothing to do with rankings. It *could* mean, Google displays only those backlinks it counts as valid / good / legit. In such case I would take a deeper look into 30-50k backlinks you get reported by other tools.

But after all it can come to light, that everything is OK and Google is just a bit idle with displaying backlinks in GSC.

In general it is not a kind of diagnosis you should become nervous about.

Comment: They update backlinks report from year to year :D .What a speed (Y)